# Как сделать, чтоб несколько сайтов работали из одной папки на сервере?

Tags: apache

Здравствуйте! Мне надо сделать, чтоб много поддоменов подтягивались из одной и той же папки на сервере. То есть отличатся внешне они будут - у каждого будет свои таблицы в базе и стили, но вот, чтоб работало это все с одного движка.
Подскажите что нужно сделать в настройках сервера, чтоб все эти сабдомены отправлялись в одну папку. Сам я в настройках сервака не особо разбираюсь, так что буду благодарен даже просто за полезные статьи на эту тему.

Comment: какого сервера? на чем он? ваш вопрос абстрактен донельзя.

Comment: Apache. Так же там установлен ISP Meneger

Comment: так добавьте в панели aliases для сайта а домены через htaccess или через движок определяйте. Или сделайте wildcard DNS для сайта. Ваш вопрос всячески надо расширить. Не понятно, что вы не умеете, домены добавлять или программировать данную структуру.